# Can we send and receive email via Amazon SES?

Tags: email, amazon-web-services, amazon-ses

I have set up `Amazon SES` for sending emails from my Java application. I also need to receive emails. I see that there is an option to receive emails using `SES`. But the docs are bit confusing. If I understand them correct, we can only receive emails from the domains that we own using `SES`. 
The following doc says the same:
[SES Doc](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/receiving-email-getting-started-verify.html)

I just want to know if SES will help me to receive emails from or to various domains including `Gmail` or only from the domains I own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can receive emails from any email address/domain using AWS SES.

Edit: The process of verifying the domain is to prove that you own/control it (the domain), but once you verify it you can send email to any domain, and receive email from any domain. The verification has to do with allowing you to receive email for that domain, or send email via that domain - it has nothing to do with the domain of the people that send you an email.

> Before you can receive email for a domain using Amazon SES, you must
>   prove that you own the domain by verifying it with Amazon SES.
>   Although Amazon SES enables you to verify single email addresses, you
>   must verify a domain if you want to use Amazon SES for email
>   receiving. You can verify and receive email with Amazon SES for any
>   domain that you own, but it is easier to set up a domain that you have
>   registered with Amazon Route 53.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/receiving-email-getting-started-verify.html

Comment: then why do we need to verify the domain. That part confuses me

Comment: you need to verify domain when you set it up, but that is *Your* domain, not the domain of people that want to email you. It would be impossible to verify  every domain that wanted to send you an email.

Answer (score 0):

Currently Amazon do additional restriction. When you create new SES account, you are in sandbox.

> However, when your account is in the sandbox, we apply the following restrictions to your account:

- You can only send mail to verified email addresses and domains, or to the Amazon SES mailbox simulator.
- You can only send mail from verified email addresses and domains.
- You can send a maximum of 200 messages per 24-hour period.
- You can send a maximum of 1 message per second.

To be able to send emails to different domain you should [Moving Out of the Amazon SES Sandbox](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/request-production-access.html)

To be able to receive emails, you must forward them to services like `S3` or `WorkMail` for example

[See also](https://jeremyfelt.com/2016/05/22/send-receive-email-domain-postmark-amazons-ses-s3-lambda-services/)